# Will other browse page effects the result of the performance.now() function

Tags: angular, performance-testing

I am testing my angular project with `performance.now()` method. In testing environment, I have multiple tab and page opened in google chrome. Will these pages and tab effects the result `performance.now()` method and ruined the accuracy? Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect from `performance.now()` that could make any other pages have any influence? All it does is report the time that elapsed since the page was open, so in and by itself, anything that happens outside will not affect it, it will still "report the time that elapsed since the page was open". However, having your computer more or less busy doing anything else may have an influence over everything that should happen **before** you call that method.

Comment: So performance.now() result will get effected because the process before it is effected. My expectation is performance.now() will runs the process individually but Its not from what I hear. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Well not really, once again that depends on what you expect it for. You talk about the "accuracy" of the result. This won't be affected at all, the method will still return a DOMHighResTimestamp, with relatively high precision and thus accuracy. If you're using it to measure how long it took to reach the line of code that does call it, then yes, that whole process might be affected, but it's not really the call to `performance.now()` that's affected, it's the rest of the execution. And we can't tell you if that rest of the execution will be affected if we don't tell us what it is.

Comment: Like I will get a slower process in my testing instance web page if I run youtube video in other page at the same time. From what I understand, yes performance.now() is accurate at telling the time. But still the end result is not to the fact because the subject it is recording time at is effected and are different. Can I look at it this way?

Comment: Once again that depends on what "the subject" is. We can't provide an answer to your question as it is, apart from a not very helpful *no `performance.now()` on itself is not impacted by other processes*.  "The end result" may very well not be impacted either, it depends on what is being measured, and on what else may happen in parallel.

Comment: I am measuring the time from - the function triggered by user pressing a button, to - api calls, returned an observable after calls is finished.